# How do I interpolate subtraction in a Ruby string

Tags: ruby

How do you do subtraction inside a string? I get zero instead of 90 percent.

```
#!/bin/ruby
puts " some text #{100%10} some text "
```

Comment: You are right, you get zero instead of 90 percent. You seem to be using it correctly. Your question is not clear.

Comment: Well at least one person understood "spickermann" and that whats matters :-)

Comment: But thank you to anyone who down-voted my question. This just shows that when people can't answer the question they simply down-vote it. Instead of asking in the comments for better explanation ^_^ Kids...

Comment: @sawa, this merge keep is for my old account > http://stackoverflow.com/users/1234619/tux  But then again you know better ^_^ since you're smart programmer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%` is an alias for `modulo`.

```
10 / 3  #=> 3
10 % 3  #=> 1
```

I guess you want to write:

```
puts " some text #{100 - 10}% some text "
```

Comment: @sawa The full modulo division can be used as `10.divmod(3)` (result is `[3, 1]`). If you need only the 1 you can use `10%3`, the 3 can be calculated with `10/3`.

Comment: @spickermann, yes I needed this #{100-10}% Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

Answer is zero in this case because `100%10` is 0, i.e. the remainder of the division is 0. 100 is evenly divisable by 10. Maybe you meant to use `-` instead?

Comment: Yeah, I've accepted "spickermann" answer :-)